# Copy rotation doesnt work correctly

Tags: modeling, rigging

I want to rig the eyelids of my character but when i use copy rotation, the eyelid rotates 90 degrees that also happens with the lower eyelid when i use invert x  [I follow this turtoriel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3Q3oD7A1kM&t=432s)
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds as if you may have missed applying the rotation to the UV Sphere that makes up the eyelids at [2.14](https://youtu.be/y3Q3oD7A1kM?t=134) into the tutorial.

Comment: ah ok, i immediately switched to the rigging part because i already finished the eyes before i watched the turtoriel

Comment: Did that cure the problem?

Comment: nothing changed, now when i use track to i can only rotate the eye on a axis where its looking up

Comment: We'll need to see the Blend file in that case (with just the eyes and armature if the whole file is very large). https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: i added the blend file

Comment: No armature bones for the eyes in that Blend file so I can't check it and the rotation hasn't been applied on the eyelids anyhow.

Comment: i updated it and i thought i had to apply only on the uv sphere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138070/discussion-between-john-eason-and-louis).